# how to open a new window with double click on control added at runtime C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am adding a moveable PictureBox control at runtime in my application as shown in the code below. I would like that when I double click on the PictureBox control, which is added at runtime, a new window opens. I tried to add an event of double click, but it's not working. Can you guide me on this how can I open a new window when double clicking on the added PictureBox control at runtime?

```
PictureBox[] PicArray;
PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();

pb.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Esp_Calculator\ESP Planner\1206570458690641104johnny_automatic_bridge.svg.med.png");
pb.Location = new Point(0, 0);
pb.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
pb.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;

pb.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.drawArea_MouseDown);
pb.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(this.drawArea_MouseMove);
pb.MouseDoubleClick += pb_MouseDoubleClick;

drawArea.Controls.Add(pb);

List<PictureBox> lblList = new List<PictureBox>();

foreach (Control d in Controls)
    if (d is PictureBox)
        lblList.Add((PictureBox)d);

        PicArray = lblList.ToArray();

private void drawArea_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  move = e.Location;
}

private void drawArea_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Control Pb = (Control)sender;
    if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) != 0)
    {
        if ((Control.MouseButtons & MouseButtons.Left) != 0)
        {
            Pb.Left += e.X - move.X;
            Pb.Top += e.Y - move.Y;
        }
    }
 }

void pb_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Editor ed = new Editor();
    ed.Show();  
}
```

Comment: I don't see in that snippet where you handle the double-click event. Did you forget to post something?

Comment: is not pb.OnDoubleClick working? :O

Comment: i have added the whole snippets. Edited.
no its not working

Comment: you have to add event listener for double click. you can do something like `pb.DoubleClick  += doubleClickFuncationName`

Comment: Thanks. Double Click does the trick instead of MouseDoubleClick.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. DoubleClick does the trick instead of MouseDoubleClick Event. Thanks . Here is the answer and working code:

```
     PictureBox[] PicArray;
PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();

        pb.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Esp_Calculator\ESP Planner\1206570458690641104johnny_automatic_bridge.svg.med.png");
        pb.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        pb.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        pb.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;





        pb.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.drawArea_MouseDown);
        pb.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(this.drawArea_MouseMove);
        pb.DoubleClick += pb_DoubleClick;

        drawArea.Controls.Add(pb);

        List<PictureBox> lblList = new List<PictureBox>();
        foreach (Control d in Controls)
            if (d is PictureBox)
                lblList.Add((PictureBox)d);
        PicArray = lblList.ToArray();

      private void drawArea_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
      {
       move = e.Location;
       }
     private void drawArea_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
     {
    Control Pb = (Control)sender;
    if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) != 0)
    {

        if ((Control.MouseButtons & MouseButtons.Left) != 0)
        {
            Pb.Left += e.X - move.X;
            Pb.Top += e.Y - move.Y;


        }
    }
 }

 void pb_DoubleClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Editor ed = new Editor();
        ed.Show();
    }
```